# Render map not displaying data on screen

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, mapping, render

I can't seem to get my renderJob mapping to render out properly.  I have no errors in the console and can't figure out while nothing is showing up.  Is there a problem with the way I'm mapping the object to the index?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


const jbSampleData = [
    {
        name: 'A place',
        location: 'USA',
        engineer: "Contact Engineer",
        service: "Last install"
    },
]

class Job extends Component {
    render() {

        const renderJob = this.props.data.map((obj, idx) => {
            return (
                <div key={idx}>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            <span>Name:</span> {obj.name} < br/>
                            <span>Location:</span> {obj.location} <br />
                            <span>Engineer Contact:</span> {obj.engineer} <br />
                            <span>Service:</span> {obj.service} <br />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <renderJob />
                Hello
            </div>
        )
    }
}


Job.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.object
    )
}

Job.defaultProps = {
    data: jbSampleData
}
export default Job;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the `map` result basically an `array` in a variable `renderJob`, that is not a react component.

You need to render it like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        {renderJob}
        Hello
    </div>
)
```

Basically `<renderJob>` will get converted into:

```
React.createElement(renderJob, null);    //new custom element
```

But in case of `{renderJob}`  its value will get replaced, and all the ui items that variable is having will get rendered.

> Why it is not throwing the error with `<renderJob/>` ?

Because name is stated with small letter so it will be considered as a built-in component like div etc, if you use `<RenderJob/>` it will throw error that `RenderJob is not defined.`

As per **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)**:

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string 'div'
>   or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

Comment: Oh thank you - been awhile since I have used React and for some reason treated it as a component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<renderJob />` change to `{renderJob}`